# Configuring additional SRC in qwc2

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, web-service, qgis-server, react

I'm working in a web map based in QGIS server and Qgis Web Client 2(QWC2).

based on the documentation in github (https://github.com/qgis/qwc2-demo-app/blob/master/doc/QWC2_Documentation.md#quick-start) to add a new projection we need to add a new line in appConfig.js file using this comand **Proj4js.defs(, );**

based on this i add the line below in the file, as you can see in the image

Proj4js.defs('31983','Extent: -48.00, -33.50, -42.00, 5.13
Proj4: +proj=utm +zone=23 +south +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs');

[image: appConfig]

and after that i got a white web page. 
i've tried to edit the **BottomBar.jsx** and the **CoordinateUtils.js** but none of it have worked too.

Comment: What does the browser console show?

Comment: only a white pag. nothing else and a get no compile error message from the console.

Comment: To exclude a syntax issue: does it work if you add the following to the projections in config.json (and remove the definition from appConfig.js):

{
      "code": "EPSG:31983",
      "proj": "+proj=utm +zone=23 +south +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs",
      "label": "SIRGAS 2000 / UTM zone 23S"
    }